# I can't get a specific value from a dictionary returned by a jQuery.get()

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

Sorry, I know this question is easy, but I don't know how to get the response data
from a returned dictionary:

This is my jQuery.get() method:

```
$("#selectDireccion").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        if ($(this).index() != 0) {
            valorKeyId = $(this).val()
            $.get("/ajaxRequest?opcion=obtenerSedeKeyId", {
                keyId: valorKeyId
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data)
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

This is what the alert prints:

```
{"name": "First Value", "phone": "434534"}
```

How should I do to get the value from the 'name' key of the dictionary?

Doing `data.name` inside an alert has no effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are returning a JSON string.  If that is the case, then you first need to run jQuery's [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function:

```
var d = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(d.name); // Will output the name from the JSON string.
```

Or, better yet (per the comment by [@calvin L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138261/calvin-l)), use the jQuery [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to begin with:

```
$.getJSON("/ajaxRequest?opcion=obtenerSedeKeyId",{keyId:valorKeyId}, function(data){
    alert(data.name); // Data already parsed to JSON, outputs the name
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call `parseJSON` jquery takes care of that based on the MIME type returned from the server... from the sample in the question it looks like he already has a javascript object parsed

Comment: You can also use `$.getJSON` instead of just `$.get`, which will automatically call `$.parseJSON` as well.